# Terraform resolving Cloudformation Outputs

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation

I have a terraform deployment which it deploys the SNS topic from a CloudFormation stack.
I export the ARN of the SNS topic but i am struggling to consume the output in TF

```
      "Outputs" : {
    "ARN" : {
      "Description" : "Email SNS Topic ARN",
      "Value" : { "Ref" : "EmailSNSTopic" }
    }
  }
}
```

The output is ARN.
But how do i construct the outputs.tf file to allow my to pick up the cf output in further TF files?

The cf stack name is named "TOPIC" as an example with an export of "ARN"
Reading the TF docs, they have an example but its failing:

```
data "aws_cloudformation_export" "arn" {
  name = "myARN"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-abb07bcb"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = data.aws_cloudformation_export.myarn.value
}
```

Is this correct?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Do you have to use the Cloudformation output? Have you considered either creating the SNS topic in Terraform directly with the [`aws_sns_topic` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/sns_topic) or using the [`aws_sns_topic` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/sns_topic)? And what error are you getting with your worked example? It looks like you're trying to use an SNS topic ARN as the subnet ID which I'd expect to fail but I'm not sure if your example is incomplete there?

Answer (score 4):

Your `Ref` attribute for the value of the output is wrong. Try with `SNSTopic` instead of `EmailSNSTopic`

Complete example :

CloudFormation `templates/cf_aws_sns_email_stack.json.tpl` :

```
{
 "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "SNSTopic": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
      "Properties": {
        "TopicName": "${sns_topic_name}",
        "DisplayName": "${sns_display_name}",
        "Subscription": [
          ${alarms_recipients_emails}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs" : {
    "ARN" : {
      "Description" : "SNS Topic ARN",
      "Value" : { "Ref" : "SNSTopic" }
      }
    }
}
```

Then if you have this in terraform :

```
data "template_file" "aws_cf_sns_stack" {
   template = file("${path.module}/templates/cf_aws_sns_email_stack.json.tpl")
   vars = {
     sns_topic_name        = "your_topic_name"
     sns_display_name      = "your_topic_display_name"
     alarms_recipients_emails = join(",", formatlist("{\"Endpoint\": \"%s\",\"Protocol\": \"%s\"}", var.alarms_recipients_emails, "email"))
   }
 }
 resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "tf_sns_topic" {
   name = "your_cf_name"
   template_body = data.template_file.aws_cf_sns_stack.rendered
 }
```

From the terraform you can use the ARN output with `aws_cloudformation_stack.tf_sns_topic.outputs.ARN`. Let's say you want a resource for a cloudwatch alarm that uses the topic created above :

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "foobar" {
  // ...
  alarm_actions       = [aws_cloudformation_stack.tf_sns_topic.outputs.ARN]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The TF module doesn't look right. Try this

```
data "aws_cloudformation_export" "my_subnet_id" {
  name = "[NAME_OF_EXPORT]"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-abb07bcb"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id     = data.aws_cloudformation_export.my_subnet_id.value
}
```

And ensure that the name property is spelled as the output of `aws cloudformation list-exports` and that you are in the same region!!

CF Exported values must be unique in a given region per account, so you don't need to reference the CF template or stack name.